# jQuery .load() isn't running PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, load

I am trying to use cURL to request from an API and dynamically change my website. Normally I would just use AJAX, but I would need to use a proxy server to overcome cross-domain restrictions since I don't own the API. I set up this very simple code snippet to see if I could get the jQuery `.load` to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="static/script.js"></script>
            <title>
                Load Test
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
                echo "php is working"
            ?>
            <div id="loadContent">
                <button id="load">Load Test</button>
            </div>
            <script>
                console.log(<?php echo '"Test"' ?>)
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#load").click(function(){
                        console.log("Load Started");  
                          $("#loadContent").load('static/curl.php')
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

curl.php was just a test and at first included just:

```php
<?php
  echo "Hello World"; 
?>
```

There was no error thrown, but the PHP did not run. I am very new to PHP, but I know that it runs before anything else is loaded and is replaced by simple HTML. I thought that it might be replacing it before I call `.load`, but it would still print "Hello World". I replaced the PHP with some HTML and it worked. I don't know enough about PHP to really debug this by myself because everything I've seen has said that this should work.

Comment: That really should work, if you print hello world you should be able to surf to curl.php and see "Hello world". Also, isn't there any feedback in the console?

Answer (score 0):

[`Load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a just [shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) of [`Ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) will still get in your way unless you run a web server.